# Rotating two spheres

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to rotate two spheres continuously both with a different rotation.
My code currently doesn't seem to get either to rotate.
Here is my code:

```
void renderScene(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0.0,1.2,-6);
        glRotatef(angle,0,1.2,-6);
        glutSolidSphere(1,50,50);           
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0,-1.5,-6);
        glRotatef(angle,0,1.5,-6);
        glutSolidSphere(0.4,50,50);
    glPopMatrix();

    angle=+0.1;
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Is there something I haven't added?
I have tried the rotate everywhere, and it only seems to work outside the push and pop matrix, which is not what I want.

Comment: You should read [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), (I'm talking about http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43412/rotating-spheres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angle=+0.1; // assign the value +0.1 to angle
```

Did you mean:

```
angle += 0.1; // increment angle by 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

`glutSolidSphere` draws a sphere around the origin: (0,0,0). `glRotatef` rotates also around an axis that passes through the origin. Now, as you probably should know, rotating a sphere around its center does not change the appearance of the sphere at all.

What you should do is first rotate and *then* translate. Like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(angle,0,1.2,-6);
    glTranslated(0.0,1.2,-6);
    glutSolidSphere(1,50,50);           
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: @Dave: then the problem must be elsewhere. E.g.: verify that the scene actually gets redrawn, that viewport is set correctly, that the model matrix is currently active, etc...

Comment: It seems to work when its outside the push and pop matrix but inside it